# How to time the execution in a container of Docker?

Tags: api, docker

I want to `time the execution of a process` in a container of `Docker`.

I tried to time it, calculating `FinishedAt` - `StartedAt` from `docker inspect`, but it's not an exact time.

I don't want to execute `time` in a container.

How can I time it exactly?

EDIT:
The process I want to time is `cmd parameter` of `docker create`.

Comment: Do you have a reproducer?

Comment: @user2915097 Sorry. What's a reproducer?

Comment: the shortest code that let somebody else do the exact same thing as you

Comment: @user2915097 Maybe, it's the same as "time" command.  http://mox.vc/VCz2

Answer (score 1):

The following creates an image that, when run, will wait for two seconds. We then run the image, outputting the overall time.  It shows that the process execution overhead is about 0.3 seconds.

## Build an image

```
$ docker create -ti ubuntu:12.04 sleep 2
785e9a63629b10676672656bc8412840faa6f00fc83e521628b0f9ca9ba01e14
```

## Time a container running the image

```
$ time docker start -i 785

real    0m2.329s
user    0m0.064s
sys 0m0.016s
```

Comment: The overhead is too big for my use. I wish it is less than 10ms.